# How do I join two tables with same column names keeping values from one the tables

Tags: postgresql

I have these two tables:

```
Table1
-------
id|a|b|c|d|
1 |0|1|0|6|
```

and

```
Table2
-------
id|a|c|
1 |3|2|
```

How do I join these two tables keeping the values from table2 but also the columns from table1, so that the table would look like this afterwards:

```
TableJoined
-------
id|a|b|c|d|
1 |3|1|2|6|
```

Tried with

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 a JOIN Table1 b WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

hoping that the first table mentioned would be the overrider

Or I guess you could do:

```
SELECT b.id, a.a, b.b, a.c, b.d FROM Table2 a JOIN Table1 b WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: I have attempted, but I didn't come close. Can post my attempt though @dfundako

Comment: So you basically answered your own question after attempting it?

Comment: Listing the columns you want is the only option you have.

Comment: Hoped there would be a better solution since the actually table has a lot of columns, and I would prefer to only mention the columns affected

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by qualifying the `*` with the table alias:

```
SELECT a.* FROM Table2 a JOIN Table1 b WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

But you should *never* use `*` in a `SELECT` list except in ad-hoc queries. (The exception is `count(*)` which is OK to use).

Comment: But wouldn't I just get the table2-columns from this query?

Comment: You asked "how do I join these two tables keeping only the values from table2?", so I thought that's what you wanted...